# Set django.setup() on another container in docker-compose. Websockets server + django app

Tags: python, django, docker, docker-compose, websocket

I am building app in docker that contains two services, one is django app and second is websockets server for playing chess which contains `client.py` `server.py` `chess.py`. Whole game is conducted by terminals, while server is running both players can play by run `client.py` in their terminals.

Now, I want to integrate websockets server with django and force players to auth by providing a token generated in `django-sesame` like in this [docs](https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/howto/django.html#validate-tokens), but I receive error on line contains `django.setup()`:

> django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting LOGGING_CONFIG, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.

I assume that I need point to django settings, but I don't have access due to it is place in another containers. How can I do that?

**Code from mentioned docs:**

```py
import asyncio

import django
import websockets

django.setup()

from sesame.utils import get_user


async def handler(websocket):
    sesame = await websocket.recv()
    user = await asyncio.to_thread(get_user, sesame)
    if user is None:
        await websocket.close(1011, "authentication failed")
        return

    await websocket.send(f"Hello {user}!")


async def main():
    async with websockets.serve(handler, "localhost", 8888):
        await asyncio.Future()  # run forever


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

I tried to point to settings by

```py
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "code.app.app.settings")
django.setup()
```

But I got error:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'code.app'; 'code' is not a package

Comment: The error looks like a module resolution problem. Could you make sure that you're running the script in the correct folder? It should be something like: `./code/app/app/settings.py` (or `./code/app/app/settings/__init__,py`)

Comment: I cannot run the script on this folder due to fact that it is placed in another container